# Camera Frustum Planes in Unity 3D

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine, plane, frustum

I understand that `CalculateFrustumPlanes()` in `Unity3D` returns an array of `Plane` objects, each representing a different frustum plane, but I can't find any documentation to suggest which element is which?

for example

```
[0] = Front  
[1] = Back
```

etc.

I need to calculate whether a point in space (like the centre point of a Bounding volume) is in the camera frustum, for a Quad tree system.

Answer (score 3):

What is exactly the order of the `Planes` in the returned array is not documented (and I don't know it).

Anyway I think you can figure it out without much effort: you just need to put the camera in a well know orientation and check the normal value's of each [Plane](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Plane.html).

> I need to calculate whether a point in space (like the centre point of
>   a Bounding volume) is in the camera frustum, for a Quad tree system.

For a Quad Tree system, I think the intersection between the frustum and a `GameObject`'s **AABB** is enough, so you don't even need to know exactly the order of the `Plane`'s in the array to compute it. You can just use [GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB.html).

Comment: Also easy, [Camera.WorldToViewportPoint](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToViewportPoint.html)(center_point)  If viewportPoint x/y are outside [0,1], point is not in frustum (or if z is negative)

Comment: @Jerdak: I think Camera.WorldToViewPoint could have even better performances in this case.

Comment: Sure, a couple less divisions.  I was too lazy to type 'if point x/y are inside [0,0] to [pixelWidth,pixelHeight].'  :)

Answer (score 3):

Order: left, right, bottom, top, near, far.